# Db2 decimal prints zero instead of rounding to decimal place

Tags: sql, db2, decimal

I'm selecting a division based on a count in DB2 and it's going into a decimal column. The problem is, it's inserting as a decimal but it's 0.00 instead of 0.74

```
select 
    CAST(180/count(*) as DECIMAL(5,2))
   from table;
```

IN this case, the count is 242 so I expect 0.74 but everything just rounds to zero.

I'm not sure on DB2 specifically what the best resolution would be here?

Comment: Use `180.0` to avoid [integer arithmetic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_arthmeticwith2integers.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a decimal point for the division:

```
select CAST(180.0/count(*) as DECIMAL(5,2))
from table;
```

As explained in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_witharithmeticoperators.html):

> - Arithmetic with two integer operands
>
> If both operands of an arithmetic operator are integers, the operation is performed in binary. The result is a large integer unless either (or both) operand is a big integer, in which case the result is a big integer.

So the `0` is appearing before the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that `CAST`ing does not round up, it just truncates. e.g. 180.0/241 would be 0.74 unless you use `ROUND` as well

```
db2 values "(180/241, 180.0/241 , cast (180.0/241 as decimal(3,2)), round(180.0/241,2), decimal(round(180.0/241,2),3,2))"

1           2                                 3     4                                 5    
----------- --------------------------------- ----- --------------------------------- -----
          0    0.7468879668049792531120331950  0.74    0.7500000000000000000000000000  0.75

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

[DB2 for Linux, Unix and Windows: Expressions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000736.html)

See the 'Decimal arithmetic in SQL' topic.
The scale is calculated by default as: 31-p+s-s'

```
db2 describe values (dec(180, 29)/242, dec(dec(180, 29)/242, 5, 2))

 Column Information

 Number of columns: 2

 SQL type              Type length
 --------------------  -----------
 484   DECIMAL               31, 2
 484   DECIMAL                5, 2


db2 values (dec(180, 29)/242, dec(dec(180, 29)/242, 5, 2))

1                                 2
--------------------------------- -------
                             0,74    0,74
```